# How can I import data from excel (xlsx, csv) to a HTML page using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, excel, csv, xlsx

H!
I have a .xlsx and .html files. How can I import the xlsx file to my html file using JavaScript, I already watched Lynda: JavaScript Essential Training by Simon Allardice and didn't get any clue how to do this! Googled a lot and still here.
Tried the similar questions...
Just need a script to copy it into my html file, and then my html file can read the xlsx and display it in the browser!

Comment: As worded, you question does not make any sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Alasql](http://github.com/agershun/alasql) JavaScript SQL library, which has special functionality to read XLSX files and put in HTML page. It uses [js-xlsx](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx) library to read XLSX files.

Disclaimer: I am the author of Alasql.

In this example:

- Alasql takes Excel file from cdn.rawgit.com (you can replace it with your address
- Alasql put result table to DIV with id="res" - you can change the name or add CSS to prettify result table
- {headers:true} flag means that Alasql reads and writes headers
- You can read CSV files as well - just replace XLSX() to CSV() in the example
- For production purpose download alasql.min.js and xlsx.core.min.js to your server or use CDN.

See the working code snippet below:

```js
alasql('select * into html("#res",{headers:true}) \
  from xlsx("https://cdn.rawgit.com/agershun/alasql/version-0.0.36/test/test168.xlsx",\
            {headers:true})')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/alasql/0.3/alasql.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.7.12/xlsx.core.min.js"></script>

<div id="res"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.
How can I apply borders and colors to this resaults?
Is there a way to apply layouts, formulas and formatting too?

Comment: For borders and layout you need to add CSS rules, see the example in jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/agershun/968zrcks/). For formulas: if you want to keep Excel formulat - you need to go js-xlsx directly (https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx). It has functionality to read formulas from spreadsheet. If you want simple predefined formulas, you can us Alasql's SELECT functionality like: SELECT *, Population*100 AS NewPop FROM XLSX("mydata.xlsx",{headers:true})

Comment: Another example with standard and user-defined formulas for data manipulation and formatting: http://jsfiddle.net/agershun/6dycw1jz/2/. If this approach is Ok for you, I can add standard formatting functions to the library.

Comment: The CSS way was fine and help me very well, Thanks again.
Now I was wondering if I can mark specific places for each td and show the content in there too. And round B and C and D cells to 1 decimal.

Comment: Please check the image: http://oi60.tinypic.com/bgv18y.jpg

Comment: For rounding - use ROUND(a,b) function like in the example http://jsfiddle.net/agershun/f11ygovs/1/. For map... let me think. Probably, you need to use d3.js library. I will try to create a sample.

Comment: This is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/agershun/LcqjLun6/2/ It reads data with cities from XLSX and reads map data from JSON file and then put city names to the map to their positions.

Comment: @agershun I have one issue, i'm thinking to use Alasql for export to excel. I want some css like bold header and a colored line between header and data. is it possible?? because i saw number of example but no where i find this.

Comment: Currently, the XLSX-JS library does not supprt coloring. I think to add additional export function based on other library