# Angularjs exporting table and c3 charts to excel sheet

Tags: angularjs, html-table, export-to-excel, c3.js

In my web application, I need to export html table and c3 charts to excel sheet. I could export table to excel by using FileSaver.js but I lost the way how to export both table and charts into one excel file. Please give me any suggestion or sample? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check this link..

[export to excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27883900/how-can-i-import-data-from-excel-xlsx-csv-to-a-html-page-using-javascript)

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/agershun/97rp0r2g/)

```
    <script src="http://alasql.org/console/alasql.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="window.exportCSV()">Export table to Excel</button>
<table width="100%">
<tr><th>Table 1</th><th>Table 2</th>
<tr><td>
<table  id="table1" border="1"  align="center" >
    <thead>
         <tr><th>ID</th><th >Name</th><th>Month</th><th>Savings</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
         <tr><td>101</td><td>John</td><td>January</td><td>$100</td></tr>
         <tr><td>102</td><td>Rianna</td><td>Feb</td><td>$200</td></tr>
         <tr><td>103</td><td>Michael</td><td>Mar</td><td>$300</td></tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
<td>
  <table  id="table2" border="1" align="center" >
     <thead>
         <tr><th>ID</th><th >Name</th><th>Month</th><th>Savings</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
         <tr><td>101</td><td>Valentin</td><td>January</td><td>$10000</td></tr>
         <tr><td>102</td><td>Olga</td><td>Feb</td><td>$20000</td></tr>
         <tr><td>103</td><td>Alesya</td><td>Mar</td><td>$300000</td></tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
```

```
window.exportCSV =    function exportCSV() {
    var data1 = alasql('SELECT * FROM HTML("#table1",{headers:true})');
    var data2 = alasql('SELECT * FROM HTML("#table2",{headers:true})');
    var data = data1.concat(data2);
    alasql('SELECT * INTO CSV("data.csv",{headers:true}) FROM ?', [data]);
}
```

I have used this one in my project..works cool :)

Comment: This is cool. But I need to export c3 line chart too, together with table.

Comment: you can map c3 line chart values to an invisible table..and then export the table values to csv/excel.